# When I try to import and use a mui avatar in react, it makes the whole div disappears

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Post.css';
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar"

function Post() {
  return (
    <div className="post">
      
      <h3>Username</h3>
      <Avatar 
          className="post__avatar"
          alt="Materialzz"
          src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
        />
        {/* header -> avatar + username */}
        <img
         className="post__image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481349518771-20055b2a7b24?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cmFuZG9tfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80"
         alt=""
         />
        {/* image */}  
        <h4 className="post__text"><strong>Username:</strong> WOW look how cool this banana looks with a pink background!</h4>
        {/* username + caption */}
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default Post
```

I was trying to make an avatar by using material ui in react. Whenever I try the examples of how to import an avatar on the Material Ui website, everything from div disappears and my screen is blank. I believe this is just a simple coding error, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Even the `<h3>Username</h3>` element disappeared?

Comment: Yes. Everything is there before I use Avatar, but the moment I use it everything disappears  and the screen is blank

Comment: Any errors in the console? Could it be possible your custom style `className="post"` conflicts with Mui?

Comment: Nope. I just changed the import method to import Avatar to "@material-ui/core/Avatar"; and now I get an error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Avatar' in 'C:\Users\menel\Instagram\instagram-clone\src'

Comment: Ok i managed to solve it. I am currently new to using react, but I believed I used a outdated version of material UI which caused the problem to occur.